# Render array of images in random order

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, if-statement

I have several Figure objects stored in an array called `figureTab`, and I'm storing used elements in an array called `used`.

Do I need to set a random number twice?
[Objects inside the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiS5f.png)

```
var used = [];
for (let i = 0; i < figureTab.length; i++) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * figureTab.length);


  if (used.length == 0) {
      used.push(random);
      html += "<div>" + (figureTab[random].FigureNr + 1) + "></div>"
  }
  else{
      for (let j = 0; j < used.length; j++) {
          if (used[j] == random) {
              random = Math.floor(Math.random() * figurTab.length);
              j = 0;
          }
       }    
       used.push(random);
       html += "<div>" + (figureTab[random].FigureNr + 1) + "></div>";
   }


document.getElementById("alternatives").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Could you please give a proper example with your question? Say sample input and the output of the input?

Comment: WTH is this: `.FigureNr` ?

Comment: I'm printing figures, and finding the image-path in the figures tab. Input: [1,2,3,4,5] Output: [3,2,5,1,4]. They're shuffled and only used once. See the image, and maybe you'll understand. I'm basicly outputting five figures randomly, and once from that figureTab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is array shuffler, there's a much shorter way to do that (implementing [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)), using [`Array.prototype.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight):

```js
const src = [{id:0, name: 'circle', path:'data:image/svg+xml;base64, PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4NCiAgPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNTAiIGN5PSI1MCIgcj0iNTAiLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg=='}, {id:1, name: 'triangle', path: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4NCsKgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLDAgaDEwMCB2MTAwIHoiLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg=='}, {id:2, name: 'rhombus', path:'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4NCsKgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik01MCwwIGw1MCw1MCBsLTUwLDUwIGwtNTAtNTAgeiIvPg0KPC9zdmc+'}, {id:3, name: 'square', path: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4NCsKgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLDAgaDEwMCB2MTAwIGgtMTAwIHoiLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg=='}, {id:4, name: 'trapezoid', path:'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4NCsKgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLDEwMCBoMTAwIGwtMjAsLTEwMCBoLTYwIHoiLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg=='}],
      wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'),

      shuffle = arr => arr.reduceRight((r,_,__,s) => 
        (r.push(s.splice(0|Math.random()*s.length,1)[0]), r),[])

shuffle(src).forEach(({name,path}) => {
  const figure = document.createElement('img')
  figure.src = path
  figure.alt = name
  wrapper.appendChild(figure)
})
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: How can I translate that into HTML, and into what I'm trying to do? Maybe rough question, I guess I need an array shuffler, but I also need to print the images - and the path to those images are stored in the array.

Comment: @ErikSkjellevik : would you describe your use case in a bit more details, so that I may adjust my answer to fulfil necessary requirements?

Comment: Unsure about the syntax, but I'll try. I have objects inside one array. figureTab = [Figure { FigureNumber: 0, Name: "Circle", Path: "/images/circle.png"}] And so on. Next figure might be a triangle, with FigureNumber: 1 and Path: "/images/triangle.png"... What I need to is to print all the figures in this array, once, and in random order. See image (in Norwegian) https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiS5f.png

Comment: Maybe this is what I need. But the main issue is that i need the path, and I think only the path. Then I'll use a for loop (?) to print all the figures with different paths. Example output:  <img src="/images/circle.png"> <img src="/images/square.png"> and so on

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions:

```
/*
- Shuffles an array properly -- without duplicates -- based on the Fischer-Yeats 
  algorithm
*/
shuffle(array)

/*
- Passes an htmlString, an array, and an optional selector of the tag that the new
  HTML will be rendered into (if no selector is provided then it will render to 
  <body> by default).
*/
function renderString(string, shuffled, selector = 'body')
```

```js
function renderString(string, shuffled, selector = 'body') {
  const node = document.querySelector(selector);
  for (let [index, url] of shuffled) {
    node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', string);
    node.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.src += url;
    node.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.textContent = index;
  }
}

function shuffle(array) {
  let qty = array.length,
    temp, i;
  while (qty) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * qty--);
    temp = array[qty];
    array[qty] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

const thumbs = [[0, '/img/link.gif'], [1, '/img/sol.png'], [2, '/img/ren.gif'], [3, '/img/balls.gif'], [4, '/img/austin.gif']];

const htmlString = `
<figure>
  <img src='https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av'>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>`;
let mixed = shuffle(thumbs);
//console.log(mixed);

renderString(htmlString, mixed, 'main');
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: start;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figure {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: 3px outset tomato;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: Well this is something. I think I'm too noob for this. Please see my comment on the other answer to maybe get a better understanding of what I'm trying to do. Or maybe you've given the answer, but I'm just a student haha rip

Comment: Ah maybe I did not iterate clearly, but I have pictures of the figures. PNGs in an Images folder. The object has a key Path and a value for example /Images/Circle.png. Therefore I cannot just print out integers.

Comment: See update, you need to provide the actual code in text form of  object not a pic.